# Why UIWindow backgroundColor normally black while the default value is nil which means clear color

Tags: ios, uiwindow

from the Apple's documentation the UIView's backgroundColor (from which UIWindow inherits) default value is nil, which means clear color
but when I freshly created a Single View Application from the template and run its window's color is black, why?

Comment: i guess it is something like an axiom to give for the most parent view a black color if it is set to clear

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really make sense to have a clear window so Apple presumably set it to a default black color, at some point you have to choose a color for the screen.

If you force the `UIWindow` to be clear then the screen is still black because the color behind the window is black.

Comment: how can i change the color please?